# Нужно небольшое уточнение к решению задачи

Tags: javascript, html, background, style, table

Напишите код, который выделит все ячейки в таблице по диагонали.

1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1
1:2 2:2 3:2 4:2 5:2
1:3 2:3 3:3 4:3 5:3
1:4 2:4 3:4 4:4 5:4
1:5 2:5 3:5 4:5 5:5

Вам нужно будет получить из таблицы table все диагональные td и выделить их, используя код:

```js
/* в переменной td DOM-элемент для тега <td>
td.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

А вот собственно один  из вариантов в решения:
*/
var table = document.querySelector("table");
for (var k = 0; k < table.rows.length; k++) {
  table.rows[k].cells[k].style.background = 'red';
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
</table>
```

Мне не совсем понятна логика решения.. Как получается так что при переборе строк в цикле мы получаем ячейки по диагонали слева направо ?

Comment: Извиняюсь,но картинку с таблицей не получилось добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кхм, кхм. На первой итерации красится нулевая ячейка в нулевой строке, на второй - первая ячейка в первой строке, и так далее.

Опасность в том, что строк может быть больше, чем столбцов.